# Мультипликативное хеширование

Tags: c++, хеширование

Занимался созданием хеш-таблицы, где необходимо было использовать мультипликативное хеширование. Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я его реализовал? 
tableSize = 10;

```
int Hash(int key) {
    float f;
    f = key*0.6180339887499; 
    f = f - (int)f;
    return 10 * f;
}
```

Comment: Если кратко, то нет — не верно... как минимум не должно быть ни какой арифметики с плавающей точкой...

Comment: А как тогда верно? Можно пример?

Comment: гм... если подумать, то согласно определению в принципе верно, хотя и крайне непрактично: когда говорят о мультипликативном хешировании обычно рассматривают только таблицы размером 2^n, для них целочисленный вариант получается довольно естественным, а вот для не-круглых размеров что-то у меня нет идей, как это сымитировать...